# Does the sum of infinitely many orthogonal projections converge with respect to the operator norm?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $E\subset H$ be an orthonormal set in $H$. For $F\subset E$, let $P_{F}\colon H\to H$ denote the orthogonal projection on the closed linear span $\bigvee F$ of $F$. Now let $F_{1},F_{2},\ldots\subset E$ be pairwise disjoint subsets of $E$. I have shown that for every $h\in H$, we have $$\sum_{k\geq0}P_{F_{k}}h=P_{\bigcup_{k\geq0}}h.$$ Now I want to say something about the convergence (or non-convergence) of $\sum_{k\geq0}P_{F_{k}}$ in $\mathscr{B}(H)$ with respect to the operator norm. Sadly enough, I can't even think of an example that satisfies the conditions of this setting. Any suggestions to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not true. Let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Let $F_k=\{e_k\}$. Then $P_{F_k}x= \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$ and the series $\sum \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$ does not converge in operator norm becasue the operator norm of the general term is $1$: $\sup \{\|\langle x, e_k \rangle e_k\|: \|x\| \leq 1\} =1$ for each $k$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I agree with you that $P_{F_{k}}x=\langle x,e_{k}\rangle e_{k}$ and that $\sup\{\|\langle x,e_{k}\rangle e_{k} \ | \ \|x\|\leq1\}=1$ for all $k\geq0$. Can you elaborate how this implies that the series $\sum_{k\geq0}\langle x,e_{k}\rangle e_{k}$ does not converge with respect to the operator norm?

Comment: If  a series converges w.r.t. any norm then the norm of the  $n-$th term must tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @Jens To be explicit if $S_n(x)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k$ then convergence in operator norm means there exists an operator $S$ such that $\|S_n-S\| \to 0$. SO $\|S_{n+1}-S_n\| \leq \|S_{n+1}-S\|+\|S-S_n\| \to 0$. But $\|S_{n+1}-S_n\| =1$ for all $n$ since $(S_{n+1}-S_n)x=\langle x , e_{n+1} \rangle e_{n+1}$.